# VueJS - create component programmatically by name

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I'm trying to build a dynamic Vue system, where I want to insert custom components knowing only their name. Inspiration from [here](https://css-tricks.com/creating-vue-js-component-instances-programmatically/) took me to do:

```js
  export default {
    name: 'MySite',
    mixins: [MyMixin],
    components: {MyComponent1, MyComponent2},
    ...
    }
    ...
    mounted() {
    
    var ComponentClass = Vue.extend(MyComponent1)
    var instance = new ComponentClass()
    instance.$mount() // pass nothing
    this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
    }
```

Now I want to do the same thing, but knowing only the component name 'MyComponent1' as String. What is the way to do it ? I guess it's more related to pure JavaScript than Vue, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you are right is a simple js.

look at the example below, most importend thing is `eval()`

```js
class Polygon {
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
  
  get getHeight() {
    return  this.height
  }
}

// js string code
var code = "new Polygon(15, 200)";
// convert it to code;
var cls = eval(code);

console.log(cls.getHeight)
```

Comment: Already tried to replace 'Vue.extend(MyComponent1)' with 'Vue.extend(eval('MyComponent1'))' but with no success..

Comment: did you try `var instance = eval("Vue.extend(MyComponent1)")`

Comment: that doesn't work, I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined error

Comment: yes then you should use `eval("import vue from 'vue'; var instance = Vue.extend(MyComponent1)")` when you do eval, the executed code execute outside the current document so if vue is not global im afraid that eval wont work for you

Answer (score 0):

I found that using

```
this.$options.__proto__.components['MyComponent1']
```

works and do what I want. Is it the cleanest solution ?